# bad connection error in managed database mysql

Tags: mysql, database, etimedout

I am using the sails.js framework and `Sails_sql` adaptor in my project. I tried to connect with the MySQL managed database I am getting the below error.

> OperationalError [AdapterError]: Unexpected error from database adapter: `select` failed ("badConnection").  A connection either could not be obtained or there was an error using the connection.

Additional data:

```
{
  error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/jenkins/workspace/services/node-services/service-latest/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:419:13)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Kindly help me the above issue to resolve.